# Treeset printing only one element and should get names in ascending order

Tags: java

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeSet;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        TreeSet<Employee> ts = new TreeSet<Employee>();
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        Employee emp2 = new Employee();
         emp1.setName("CDD");
         emp2.setName("BCC");
         ts.add(emp1);
         ts.add(emp2);
         Iterator<Employee> itr=ts.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                Employee c=itr.next();
                System.out.println(c.getName());
            }
    }
}

public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> 
{   
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }



}
```

I am adding custom `Employee` Objects to the tree set to get the names in the ascending order.

I have this program.

Could you please let me know:

1. Why only one elemnt is being shown
2. How to get the names in ascending order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a `compareTo` method that won't compare all `Employee`s equal, which is what your `compareTo` method is doing by always returning `0`.  When a `TreeSet` (or any `Set`) finds an object that is "equal" to something already in the set, it won't add it.

You can compare `Employees` by comparing their names.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee arg0) {
    return this.name.compareTo(arg0.name);
}
```

Or you can create your own implementation of `compareTo`, returning a negative number when this object is "less than" the object argument, `0` when this object is "equal to" the object argument, and a positive number when this object is "greater than" the object argument, per the [`compareTo` contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-).

Comment: Interessting, that the JavaDoc of `TreeSet.add` is wrong here, because it says "More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no element e2 such that `(e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2))`" and that returns `false`. Should be added that `compareTo` counts if the passed type implements the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: @Tom In general `Set`s do use `equals`, but `TreeSet` breaks from this by using `Comparable` objects or a `Comparator`.  But its [Javadocs do state](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html): "Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface.".  To be consistent with equals, @Kiran would also need to define an `equals` method that compares the employee names.

Comment: Thanks , i have got my equals method as @Override
     public boolean equals (Employee other)
     {
         if (!(other instanceof Employee))
             return false;
         Listed ob = (Listed) other;
         return name.equals(ob.name) ;
     }

Comment: @rgettman It needs to be consistent for using other methods than `add`, since this methods relies solely on `compareTo`.

Comment: @Kiran You need to override `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: Thanks , hashcode is  @Override
     public int hashCode ()
     {
         return Arrays.hashCode(new String[]{name});
     }

Comment: please let me know if thats fine

Comment: If you're using an IDE like Eclipse, then let it generate these methods for you. For example your equals method `Listed ob = (Listed) other;` .. what is `Listed`?